# Assigning values to an array from an initializer list

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array declared `private` in my header file. When I try to put values into it from `main`, i get errors saying it is private and assigning values to an array from an initializer list.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(){
ArraySet<string> bag;
bag.items = { "a", "b", "c"};

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

items is defined in my header as :

```
template <typename ItemType>
class ArraySet : public SetInterface<ItemType>{
private:
ItemType items[CAPACITY];
static const int CAPACITY = 6;
```

Is this the incorrect way to do this? I am new to templates. Thank you!

Comment: What was the last thing you added to this code? I ask because you're doing a couple of different things wrong.

Comment: I created a void function that copies the contents of one array (items), using a for loop into another array with the exact same characteristics. Now I'm just trying to put elements into item so I can copy them. The very last thing I added was the set.items = { ... }

Comment: Also, it's not a good idea to use 'set' as a variable name since it is the name of a data structure too.

Comment: Is it possible to assign values from main? Or do I need to create some sort of method that will do this? I just want to be able to interchange the contents of the item array.

Comment: `main` is special because it's the entry point to your program which gets called when the runtime starts your executable. It is, however, a normal function just like any other and you can do whatever you like in main. Of course it's good practice to call properly named functions from main instead of doing all the work there but in your case it doesn't matter that the code is in main.

Comment: I think you also have misunderstood access modifiers (public, protected, private, ...), since declaring the ArraySet `private` stops you from assigning it from outside. You need to make it `public` or create a public method in `ArraySet` which does the assignment for you.

Comment: You can't assign elements to an array that way, and you can't modify private members directly from outside the class. (You should have tried these two new things one at a time.) Which one do you want help with?